Dirac comb from the point of view of QM
There is a rather peculiar object in mathematics, called the Dirac comb. It has an interesting property that (properly rescaled) it satisfies $\mathcal{F}w=w$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform (original notation uses the cyrillic letter ,,sha'' but let me denote the Dirac comb simply by $w$). It means that it has a similar property as the standard Gaussian have, namely it is an eigenvector of Fourier transform. However, it is not an ordinary function i.e. it does not belong to the Hilbert space $L^2$-rather, it is tempered distribution (so it is in fact a so called generalized eigenvector ). Since standard Gaussian is very important in Quantum Mechanics (and not only there!) being a state which minimizes uncertainty for position and momentum operators, I wonder whether there is some significance of the Dirac comb in QM. I'm aware that the Dirac comb is important from the point of view of signal processing but I'm specifically interested in significance of it in Quantum Mechanics.

Taking the Dirac comb as an external potential leads to a very prominent example of a (model) solid: The so-called Kronig-Penney model.

"... being a state which minimizes uncertainty for position and momentum operators" No, the Dirac comb is not a valid quantum state because it is not normalizable. So the conclusion about the uncertainty does not apply.

@flippiefanus I think the sentence is about the Gaussian.

If you are only motivated by fixed points of the Fourier transform, then they form quite a large space. It is spanned by every fourth quantum harmonic oscillator energy eigenvectors. The gaussian is precisely the ground state and the Dirac comb can be viewed as a superposition of them.
